# UITableViewCell with semi transparent selected background

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I need to hide the normal (unselected - cell.backgroundView) image of a cell when the cell is selected and show it when it is not selected.

The way the tableview works is that the normal view (cell.backgroundView) is always there and when the cell is selected it animates the selected image (cell.selectedBackgroundView) into view and places on top of the normal view.

The problem is when the selected cell is semitransparent and the normal cell is always visible underneath it.
I created, in 2 views for my (custom) UITableViewCell which I load in my view controller:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
 willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell 
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"XYCell"]];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"XYCellSelected"]];
}
```

I cleared colors from in the required places but I cannot get it to work as I want.
Since my selected images (cell.selectedBackgroundView ) is semitransparent, the cell.backgroundView can still be seen underneath it.
How can I make it go away?

Comment: You could try setting `cell.backgroundView.alpha = 0.0f;` when the cell gets selected.

Comment: I added to my:
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].backgroundView.alpha = 0.0f;

This did the work but I keeps the cell with alpha=0 even when I select another cell.

Comment: You need to somehow track the selected cell (ex. store reference in member variable) and set the alpha back to 1.0f, when you select another.

Answer (score 1):

In general, if you want a custom cell you should implement your own uitableviewcell.

In your case take a look at

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

Code example to help you :

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
   [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];
   //your own backgroundview when selected
   self.selectedBackgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selectedBck.png"]];
   if (selected){
        // edit the cell's view when it's selected
        self.backgroundView = nil;
    } 
    else {
       // edit the cell's view when it isn't selected
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    self.highlightIndexPath = indexPath;    // for iOS6
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.backgroundView.hidden = YES;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didUnhighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (indexPath.row == NSNotFound) {
        // for iOS6
        cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.highlightIndexPath];
    }
    cell.backgroundView.hidden = NO;
}
```